# Why isn't trash ground into dust and used as fuel?

Tags: energy-efficiency, energy

Combustible dust is known as an explosion hazard, especially in large factories etc. They can create powerful explosions and bring down entire buildings if it is disturbed by a large enough vibration and then sparked.

My theory is that by drying out and grinding up trash, especially if done at the nano level for further efficiency, and with proper filtration and machine lubrication the energy could be harnessed, and the fuel doesn't need anything but a spark to ignite.

Trash is readily available and even what some would consider in the way considering it just sits in land fills emitting poisonous gas and possibly radiation in later stages. Note: This paragraph is obsolete and trash is already incinerated regularly as a means of energy.

---

Try this at home. Very slowly and incrementally pour some coffee creamer and light the trail. Anything is highly flammable and creates a somewhat explosive reaction, however small, it will engulf the entire stream vertically upward, creating a way to not only burn the fuel but the air around it. I would compare that to the electron duplicating characteristics of a mirror.

---

Also general nanotechnology is in the experimental stages. To draw an unrelated idea, the friction reduction capabilities of dry lithium come from something called a basal plane, in crystal structures consisting of edges and even gaseous or liquid bearing cavities. A good example would be the bottom of a soda can. In a small puddle it closes the cavity and creates buoyancy allowing it to glide like a hovercraft. You could even use the nanodust theoretically in a synthetic nano crystal, giving you a low friction, leak free means of lubrication with no grease buildup, breakdown or dust problems.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up "dust" and "trash" into one question, whereas I think they might be separate ones. "Trash" is already burnt and turned into energy in incinerators, although most councils in the UK like to call them "Energy Recovery Facilities".

Comment: Also, don't confuse the speed of a combustion reaction with how much energy it releases.  Just because you grind up a fuel into a nano-powder doesn't mean it will release more energy; just means it will burn faster.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the edits have turned it into a discussion which is off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Combustible dust ***is*** used as a source of fuel, just not exactly in the scenario that you envisioned.

Coal-fired power plants first grind the chunks of coal into powder that's small enough to be injected into the burners.  There's a considerable amount of <strike>alchemy</strike> chemistry involved based upon the composition of the coal.  Grinding the coal prior to burning provides a more consistent size and a greater surface area which results in a more easily regulated and controlled combustion.

Trash is sometimes used as a fuel source, but not as frequently as it once was.  The biggest challenge here is controlling the amount of pollutants that go out as part of the exhaust.  To my knowledge, an additional challenge in burning trash is a relatively low energy yield combined with a comparatively higher pollutant profile.  More pollutants mean greater amounts of scrubbing and therefore a lower yield from the power plant.

Regarding grinding to trash to nano scale, I suspect that doing so is well past the point of reasonable returns.  It will take more energy to process to this level than what you'll see in return post-combustion.